# Remove Number and Dot from a string using Ragex in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to remove the numbers, decimal present after number (no after character) using Regax.

example: let i have a string name abc4.5,asdjh44400.555 and dasqw123123.

then the output should be abc,asdjh and dasqw.

it should remove all the numbers and replace with empty string.

I searched in google tried to do the above requirement but didn't succeed.

i have tried

```
var abc = "asp.net 4.5";
alert(abc.replace("[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?", ""));`
```

Please help me to find the solution using java script.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'abc4.5,asdjh44400.555 and dasqw123123.'.replace(/\d+.\d+/g,'') // -> abc,asdjh and dasqw.
```

Comment: Can we remove .(dot) also?

Comment: That is just what you expected in your example: abc4.5,asdjh44400.555 and dasqw123123. -> abc,asdjh and dasqw.

Comment: The qbove one is working fine 
thanks CD..
One Query
I want this should not apply to some word like HTML5,CSS3 etc.
then i have write another regex or we can do that one with this.

Comment: Yes, use this - 'abc4.5,asdjh44400.555 and dasqw123123.'.replace(/\d*[.]?\d*/g,'')